# SQL Server allows me to CREATE SEQUENCE on 2008 Compatibility level (100)

Tags: sql-server

As stated in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql), CREATE SEQUENCE is supported from Version 2012. I have a database in 2008 compatibility (100) because the product is deployed at clients having this version. Our development servers are 2014.

We created a script to create a SEQUENCE object and it ran OK on our development servers (2014 in 2008 mode). When we tried running it on our 2008 staging environment it failed (as expected).

My question is why would a database in 2008 compatibility allow a feature that is not supported in 2008?

Comment: You're thinking of the compatibility settings the wrong way around. It makes sure that features that existed in both versions of the product will act as if you're running the older version of the product. They're not, specifically, designed to prevent you from using newer features that did not exist on the older version of the product.

Comment: Thanks Damien. That makes sense. Is there any way (other than install a 2008 server) to achieve this (not allowing newer features)? It's a nice feature to have when handling multiple databases on one development machine.